# Como alterar form conforme cookies

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html5

Estou trabalhando num site de apostas, gostaria de saber como posso fazer para quando a pessoa aposta, mudar a visualização daquela aposta (mostrar como já feita a aposta e dar o link caso queira editar). Lembrando que tem que ser conforme o login da pessoa, e as apostas estão num while, então tem que saber diferenciar a aposta que já foi feita da que não foi feita.

Espero ter sido Claro, senão me peçam para explicar melhor caso não tenha entendido.

Comment: poste seu código. Como você esta salvando a aposta? BD? COOKIE?

Comment: Acredito que você não está fazendo um bom uso dos recursos dos cookies, explique melhor o seu problema e inclua os trechos de código relvantes para a solução do problema.